# No module named Snowflake found

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a notebook on a SageMaker instance at my work. My goal is to connect my jupyter notebook to the snowflake database so as to query some data.
Here are some details regarding my problem;

```
(practiceenv) sh-4.2$ python --version
Python 3.8.6
```

In the same environment, I did run the command;

```
conda list
```

And I could see the package;

```
# Name                    Version                   Build      Channel
 snowflake-connector-python 2.3.10                    py38h51da96c_0    conda-forge
```

So it seems the correct package is there. Next, I did create a jupyter notebook(condapython3 kernel) in the same environment and tried to import the package

```
import snowflake.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake
```

I was able to get the dependencies installed. Please see the screenshot.[image]
May I get some help on how to debug this error? Help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you installed the packages in (practiceenv) environment. Does your notebook run in (practiceenv)? Or is it in (python3)? The documentation gives you instruction how to install the packages in desired environment. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-python-package-conda/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

Have you tried it in jupyter-notebook?

Comment: Appreciate your help. May I know, how is this different from installing using `pip` command in the terminal. Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: As per my understanding. Installing packages via jupyter-notebook scope is local or they can be used(imported) only within jupyter-notebook. But if you install pip packages via terminal they become globally installed packages. Having said that in order to use the globally installed packages the PATH needs to be set properly. This might be the reason it is showing no module found error.

Comment: I was able to rectify the error after using this command in my CMD.

Answer (score 11):

Uninstall snowflake first (pip uninstall snowflake)

Then install snowflake again(pip install snowflake-connector-python==2.8.3)

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: Just came to this solution, and it worked for the same error I was facing as the OP. It appears that having Snowflake installed prior to the snowflake-connector-python causes issues in the init.py file.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of **pip install snowflake.sqlalchemy**
with this you can get well with the connector you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error while sourcing a Python script from the R terminal (using the `reticulate` package). The R terminal was launched from the `base` conda environment. First I tried `pip install snowflake-connector-python` in the `base` environment and also in the native Python environment (conda deactivated), but it didn't work. I managed to fix the problem by opening the R terminal in the `base` environment and installing the Snowflake connector with `reticulate`:

```
reticulate::py_install("snowflake-connector-python")
```